# How to build CLion based CMake Project with custom Toolchain from Command Line

Tags: cmake, clion

I've only worked with CMake in conjunction with the CLion IDE but I'm aware that CMake projects can be built on the command line completely without the IDE with the CMake build system only.

Now I have some more complex CLion projects for which I created a custom toolchain and various profiles through the CLion menus (File -> Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment --> Toolchain / CMake). I want to switch to building these projects through Gitlab CI without CLion. But how do I start a CMake build on the command line in on a build VM without CLion installed that uses the toolchain and profiles that I created in the CLion GUI?

The desired settings to reproduce are:

- Using a custom gcc cross compiler for all profiles
- Dependent on the profile:

  - passing various CMake variables (like `-DMY_VAR=FOO`) to my CMakeLists
  - choosing a debug or release build as build type

In CLion I have one custom toolchain with the special gcc and four profiles with different settings, all using this toolchain.

Does CLion generate a toolchain file somewhere in the background that I could just use (didn't find any so far) or do I need to write my own toolchain file and pass it to `cmake`?

Comment: In the command line toolchain file is passed via `-DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=<...>` option for `cmake` executable. What exact setting in the profile you want to repropduce in the command line?

Comment: The desired settings to reproduce are: Using a custom gcc cross compiler for all profiles and dependent on the profile passing various CMake variables (like `-DMY_VAR=FOO`) to my CMakeLists as well as choosing a debug or release build as build type. So in CLion I have one custom toolchain with the special gcc and four profiles with different settings, all using this toolchain. Does CLion generate a toolchain file somewhere in the background that I could just use (didn't find any so far) or do I need to write my own toolchain file and pass it to `cmake`?

Comment: I think this information deserves to be in the question post: it makes the question much more clear and specific.

Comment: Yes, you are right, added it to the original post